# MIPS sw instruction address out of range error

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm a new-learner to MIPS and when I use MARS to try to run the code below:

```
addi $8, $0, 3
addi $9, $0, 2
add $10, $8, $9
sub $11, $8, $9
ori $12, $8, 4
add $13, $8, $9
beq $10, $13, beq_test
add $0, $0, $0
add $0, $0, $0
beq_test: sw $10, 4($0)
lw $14, 4($0)
add $0, $0, $0
add $0, $0, $0
j exit
add $0, $0, $0
add $0, $0, $0
exit:
```

The MARS throw me an error as:

```
Error in /Users/plotnickslope/Desktop/mips1.asm line 10: Runtime exception at 0x00400024: address out of range 0x00000004

Go: execution terminated with errors.
```

It seems that there is an error in the sentence `beq_test: sw $10, 4($0)` at line 10. But I don't know why it happened.
I would appreciate it if you could help me out.Thanks!

I've tried to change the number in the instruction 'beq_test: sw $10, 4($0)' but as I say, I'm a new-learner to MIPS so I didn't get any success.

Comment: The MIPS environment won't let you write to arbitrary memory locations.  You have to use valid memory locations, which can be obtained by using global data, the stack, or the heap.

Comment: In some environments, you can configure low memory (memory with small addresses like 4) to be accessible using options/settings.